# Seeking large file in c++ on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, xfs

I'm writing a small utility to parse xfs filesystem on windows. 
For small size image <5GB my utility is working fine: I'm able to list all files and directories.
But when I try to parse large xfs image > 30GB. It is giving wrong results.
I'm using _fseeki64 and _ftelli64 for seeking and fread for reading particular block.
One of thing I've notice is that _fseeki64 is not wroking properly.
Below is my seek function which seek to particular group number and block number.

```
int FileSystemReadXFS::SeekToGroupBlock(uint16_t grpNum, uint64_t blockNum)
    {
        int error = -1;
        //Seek to beginning
        if(_fseeki64(m_fileSystemInfo.fp, (__int64)0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
        {
            PRINT_SEEK_ERROR;
            goto BAILOUT;
        }
        __int64 currPtr = 0;
        //Seek to destination group
        if(grpNum > 0)
        {
            if(_fseeki64(m_fileSystemInfo.fp, (__int64)(grpNum*m_fileSystemInfo.SizeOfBlockGroup*m_fileSystemInfo.BlockSize), SEEK_SET))
            {
                PRINT_SEEK_ERROR;
                    goto BAILOUT;
            }
             currPtr = _ftelli64(m_fileSystemInfo.fp);
        }


        //Seek to destination block in group
        if(blockNum > 0)
        {
            if(_fseeki64(m_fileSystemInfo.fp, (__int64)(blockNum*m_fileSystemInfo.BlockSize), SEEK_CUR))
            {
                PRINT_SEEK_ERROR;
                goto BAILOUT;
            }
            currPtr = _ftelli64(m_fileSystemInfo.fp);
        }
        error = 0;
BAILOUT:
        return error;
    }
```

However the above function is taking me to wrong postion.
For example when I want to seek to group number = 2 with m_fileSystemInfo.SizeOfBlockGroup = 2043982
and m_fileSystemInfo.BlockSize = 4096.

I'm expecting currPrt = 2043982*4096*2 = 16744300544 (0x3E609C000), But _ftelli64 is returning (0xE609C000).
Please suggest what could be going wrong. Also please advice what is the best way to deal with large files on windows in c++.

Update::

I found that the seekOffset is getting limited to 8154365952 (0x1e609c000) instead of actual
value of 16744300544 (0x3e609c000) inspite of me using __int64.

So.

_*int64 seekOff = (*_int64)(grpNum*m_fileSystemInfo.SizeOfBlockGroup*m_fileSystemInfo.BlockSize)
                = 2*2043982*4096
 is giving 8154365952 instead of 16744300544.

I'm not sure what could the reason as everything is in __int64.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the problem was with calculation of seek offset. It was generating integer overflow.
Hence I have to convert everything to __int64 even-though I'm working on 64 bits application. I was thinking compiler might be able to do this for me.

```
__int64 grpNum = 2;
__int64 sizeOfBlockGroup = 2043982;
__int64 blockSize = 4096;
__int64 seekOffSet = grpNum*sizeOfBlockGroup*blockSize;
```

which works fine with _fseeki64 and __ftelli64.

Comment: In the memory model used for 64bit windows, pointers are 64bit but integers are 32bit. Also, you don't have to make all the values __int64, you just have to make sure that if A * B is bigger than 32bits then either A or B is __int64.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use Win32 API directly and not go through the C RunTime.

Use [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open the file and [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to seek

The functions you're calling will end up calling these APIs anyway. In Visual studio you have the CRT code so you can step into `_fseeki64` and possibly see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I found that offset calculation of 2*2043982*4096 is getting limited to  8154365952 instead of actual value of 16744300544. I've used __int64 most of the places but it doesn't help.